# Outlook Add-in: How to ajax post to another domain?

Tags: outlook-addin, browser-sync

I'm developing an Outlook Add-in with external editor (vs-code) and with browsersync.
When I try to post via ajax i got the following error:

> Failed to load
>   https://my_domain/report/v1/?id=YWFhfDIzfDMyNHwxfDl8MTE: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://my_local:8443' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

I've tried to change cors to true in bsconfig.json.

My ajax function:

```
  function ajax_post_request (url) {
    var data = []
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      async: true,
      type: 'POST',
    })
    return request
  }
```

How to enable Cors and Access-Control-Allow-Origin' correctly?

Comment: https://www.hondo.co/how-to/enable-cors-in-browsersync.html

Answer (score 0):

My final working ajax function:

```
  function ajax_post_request (url, body) {
    var request = $.ajax({
      data: body,
      crossDomain: true,
      cache: false,
      url: url,
      async: true,
      type: 'POST',
    })
    return request
  }
```

My NGINX web proxy to allow CORS:

```
...
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control';
...
```